# Can't get selenium click to work on python

Tags: python, selenium

I've been reading a few threads with the same issue but not found the solution trying what is suggested in those.

Here is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54277af16945bd645fd2

I have tried with xpath. I wasn't sure about the other searches. I tried with id but wasn't sure I had the code right since there are lots of different drop downs when inspecting element.

The browser loads but nothing happens after that when the click should come.

I want to click the login to instagram button.

Comment: Please post your code here. There's not that many lines and some day if you remove that code (or change it) this question will be worthless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xpath-expresseion seems a bit strange, try this one

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'loginwithinstagram']").click()
```

but actually you don't need xpath, since there is this unique id, you can have it in a more beautiful way ;-) :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('loginwithinstagram').click()
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Worked a treat. I didn't notice the id in inspect element; but did once I chekced after your example. Not used to using inspect element browser yet.

Comment: Hey, Im stuck again. After login I click on the profile picture in the top right to bring up the tabs along the top of: view stats, posts, albums, followers, following. 

The problem now is no id to use and I tried with class which was a long shot because its only named 'link' and it of course clicks on the first match. I tried xpath and again it did nothing. So not sure what to try next. forgot to say I want to click on the followers link.

Comment: EDIT: Never mind I got it. As you alluded to earlier my xpaths were bad and worked once I installed firebug and copied using that.

Comment: If you have another question, please don't post it as a comment... please post another question. Thanks!